# how to test project reactor code that does not return a subscription

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

i'm trying to create a component that stream data from remote service continuously. The component starts and stops according to spring container lifecycle. I'm not sure how to test this component as the subscription is done inside my component so i was wondering wether this is the correct way to implement this kind of component with webflux or not. Does anybody know any similar component in any framework from where i might take some ideas?

Regards

```
class StreamingTaskAdapter(
    private val streamEventsUseCase: StreamEventsUseCase,
    private val subscriptionProperties: subscriptionProperties,
) : SmartLifecycle, DisposableBean, BeanNameAware {
    private lateinit var disposable: Disposable
    private var running: Boolean = false
    private var beanName: String = "StreamingTaskAdapter"
    private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}

    override fun start() {
        logger.info { "Starting container with name $beanName" }
        running = true
        doStart()
    }

    private fun doStart() {
        disposable = Mono.just(
            CreateSubscriptionCommand(
                subscriptionProperties.events,
                subscriptionProperties.owningApplication
            )
        )
            .flatMap(streamEventsUseCase::createSubscription)
            .flatMap { subscription ->
                Mono.just(subscription)
                    .map(::ConsumeSubscriptionCommand)
                    .flatMap(streamEventsUseCase::consumeSubscription)
            }
            .repeat()
            .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(MAX_ATTEMPTS, Duration.ofSeconds(2)).jitter(0.75))
            .doOnSubscribe { logger.info { "Started event streaming" } }
            .doOnTerminate { logger.info { "Stopped event streaming" } }
            .subscribe()
    }

    override fun stop() {
        logger.info("Stopping container with name $beanName")
        doStop()
    }

    override fun isRunning(): Boolean = running

    private fun doStop() {
        running = false
        disposable.dispose()
    }

    override fun destroy() {
        logger.info("Destroying container with name $beanName")
        doStop()
    }

    override fun setBeanName(name: String) {
        this.beanName = name
    }

    companion object {
        const val MAX_ATTEMPTS: Long = 3
    }
}
```

Comment: put it in a function, test the function... subscribe to the function..... functions are free

Comment: Yes, that's is correct, but I would like to test the whole component and lifecycle events : start, stop, etc. Kind of integration test. Something similar to how controllers are tested on spring.

Comment: that was not included in the question, and the purpose is to test the code, not test spring framework. But if you insist on testing that spring does what it does, then setup whatever it reads from and whatever it writes to, insert data, run the service, then read and assert the result.